# Need help with REGEX in PHP. A simple one. Help!

Tags: php, regex

Recently, I'm playing with something related to BBCode in phpBB3. When I trace back my database, the posts table and for a random post. I found that the image tag is written this way **[img:fcjsgy5j]**. There are 8 random characters generated between **[img: ... ]** for each post.

```
[img:fcjsgy5j]http://imageurl.jpg[/img]
```

My question is, how can I make use of preg_replace() to replace the random characters into this way..

```
<img src="http://imageurl.jpg">
```

Comment: [You cannot parse BBCode with Regular Expressions](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html). Use a [BBCode Parser](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace("`\[img:.+?\](.*?)\[/img\]`i", '<img src="$1"/>', $input);
```

- `[` begins a character set. We don't want that; we want to match the literal `[` character, so we have to escape it with a `\`
- `.` matches any character
- `+` means we match 1 or more of the previous thing (any character)
- `?` makes the previous quantifier ungreedy (`.+` would match everything, right to the very end of the string, that's not what we want, we want it to match as little as possible... just up to the next `]`
- `(.*?)` matches all the junk between the `[img]` tags. Ungreedy again. We put `()` around it to make it mtaching set
- The ` (back-tick) at the start and the end could be any character... whatever character you start with, you have to end with. A lot of people use `/` but I prefer the back-tick because it rarely appears anywhere inside the regular expression, thus I don't need to escape it.
- The `i` at the very end means The expression will be case insensitive. (will match img, IMG, ImG, etc.)
- The `$1` in the replace refers back to the `()` section we denoted earlier... it basically takes whatever was matched there, and plops it into the place of `$1`

Comment: [a-z] will miss the 5, better to use a simple .+

Comment: @generalhenry: `.+?` you mean... otherwise it's greedy and will gobble everything up.

Comment: I always thought that you have to use delimiters in PHP regexes. Does this code actually run? I don't have PHP installed, so I can't check.

Comment: @Tim: I think you're right... I've been writing C# regexes lately, so I forgot ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I know where can I learn regular expression for php? I still don't get it after reading it again and again.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a pretty good site for learning regular expressions. I know they look confusing as heck at first, but it becomes second nature after awhile ;) Nevertheless, I'll add some more detail to my Q.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[img:[^]]+\]([^[]+)\[/img\]%', '<img src="\1">', $subject);
```

or, as a commented regex:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%\[img:  # match [img:
    [^]]+     # match one or more non-] characters
    \]        # match ]
    ([^[]+)   # match one or more non-[ characters
    \[/img\]  # match [/img]
    %x', 
    '<img src="\1">', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$search = array(
    '\[img:.+?\](.*?)\[\/img\]\'
);
$replace = array(
    '<img src="\\2">'
);
$result = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
?>
```

I used the array form of preg_replace so that u can add more search and replace patterns in the future. I think you are trying to replace some BBCODE tags. There is plenty of libraries on the net to handle BBCODE correctly.

Edited

Like this one :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: your `$search` will never match.. you didn't handle the random characters. also, you're returning....from what? this isn't in a function AFAIK.